# Debian 8 Jessie EFI dualboot Windows 8.1

Tags: debian, windows, live-usb, uefi, debian-installer

I'm quite new with EFI as I recently got EFI-enabled laptop.

```
500GB SSHD
 -> GPT
   - 80GB Window 8.1
   - 80GB Empty
   - All rest data storage
```

Now I would like to install Debian 8 Jessie to empty 80GB partition.

But:

```
 - I need to install it from USB flash drive
 - It need to offer choice between Debian and Windows. 
 - It should be EFI
```

I already have downloaded debian-live-8.0.0-amd64-kde-desktop.iso 
Just writing image with dd on another computer didn't worked, as I have expected. Laptop don't even recognize USB flash drive made in that way (only in Legacy mode).

Answer (score -1):

You may not be running Ubuntu, but here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI the Ubuntu folks describe how to install using EFI.

What you need is to create a bootable USB stick for EFI with [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and then copy the install iso onto it. Also you might need to disable Secureboot in your EFI Configuration.

A word on Windows on just a 80GB partition: It is really small and you propably are only able to install very few programs until you run out of space. As for linux it might be okay with 80GB, but still not much space to work with.

**UPDATE: Creating a boot stick to install linux**

To create a bootable USB Stick usable for EFI install on Windows run  `diskpart` and enter the following commands. Be sure to select the USB stick in select disk where you want to place the setup files for linux.

- list disk
- select disk <#>
- clean
- create partition primary
- select partition 1
- active
- format quick fs=fat32
- assign
- exit

Then mount the ISO of the linuxdistribution you want to install and just copy the contents. You then should be able to boot from the USB Stick. If not disable secure boot in EFI. To setup secureboot for Grub2 to be able to boot Windows have a look at this article http://www.boerngen-schmidt.de/2015/04/gentoo-and-windows-8-1-secure-boot-setup/

Comment: No worry about space, I don't install anything on Windows partition, if possible I install on third big partition. 
What I heard is that UNetBootin doesn't support EFI...

Comment: @xZero I updated my answer with directions on how to create a usb stick from which you can boot the installation. Hope this helps

Comment: debian images are efi-bootable, unetbootin is not required.  Check the official debian install guide. Secure-boot will need to be disabled as you say, however.  (Ubuntu & Fedora can do secure boot, so they work without fiddling on systems certified for Windows 8).

Comment: though I'm happy to admit the Debian manuals are not as friendly as they could be. See [UEFI section](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s06.html.en#UEFI) & [usb boot section](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-isohybrid)